# Finding the minimum balance given a time frame

Tags: java, database, postgresql

What is the best method by which I can calculate the minimum balance given a time frame?  In my database, I have a deposit column and a withdraw column and date column at which they are done.

***Update***

Suppose on 1/1, the balance is 300.  On 1/2, 300 is deposited with total of 600. On 1/15, 200 is withdrawn leaving a balance of 400. On 1/25, further withdrawal of 300 is made and the balance goes down to 100.  On 1/28, 800 is deposited and balance total to 900.  If on 1/31 I were to calculate the minimum balance for that month, I should get 100.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that your question is answerable as it is written. If you don't get a decent answer soon, you may want to provide a few more important details.

Comment: At least which DB you are using

Comment: Given a number of deposits and withdrawals in a specified time-period, how do you determine the lowest balance in that period, calculating daily?

Comment: I've update the question.  I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @justinhj :: At the moment I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use windowing functions to build the running balance, then extract the minimum out of each time interval like this:

```
with cte_transaction_data as
(
    select 300 as deposit, null as withdraw, date '01/02/2010' as transaction_date union all
    select null, 200, date '01/15/2010' union all
    select null, 300, date '01/25/2010' union all
    select 800, null, date '01/28/2010'
)
select
    month,
    min(balance) as minimum_balance
from
    (
        select 
            transaction_date,
            date_trunc('month', transaction_date) as month,
            300 
            + coalesce(sum(deposit) over(order by transaction_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row), 0)
            - coalesce(sum(withdraw) over(order by transaction_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row), 0) as balance
         from cte_transaction_data
    ) as running_balance
group by
    month
order by
    month
```

Result:

```
month                   minimum_balance
2010-01-01 00:00:00-06  100
```

Comment: Two thumbs up my friend.  Looks like this is going to work for me for now.  Thanks.

Comment: : By the way what do UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING do?

Comment: They set the range of other rows within the partition (in this case all rows) that should be considered in the windowing function (in this case sum).  So in this case sum is the running sum of all rows between the first row and the current row when ordered by transaction date.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each entry in the database for every day that there was a deposit/withdrawal and store the lowest number in a variable. If the number for the day being checked is lower, replace the variable with that number.